# How to update chained dropdown value in Dash dcc?

Tags: python, dynamic, callback, plotly-dash

In dash, how do I update the values of one dropdown into another checklist or slider?
In the below code, I am selecting one value from a dropdown which should update checklist values based on the selected value from the dropdown. Here I am partially successful in taking value from the dropdown but it's **accumulating with older selected values in the checklist**.
Please find below part of the code.

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv')

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True

app.layout = html.Div([
                dash_table.DataTable(
                        id='datatable-upload-container',
                        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                        data=df.to_dict('records'),
                        ),
                html.Div(dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='data_selector1',
                    options=[
                        {'label': '', 'value': ''}
                        ],
                    value=[]
                    )
                ),
                html.Br(),
                html.Div([
                    html.Div(id='numerical-slider'),
                    # this is a hack: include a hidden dcc component so that
                    # dash registers and serve's this component's JS and CSS
                    # libraries
                     dcc.Input(style={'display': 'none'})
                ])
           ])

@app.callback(Output('data_selector1', 'options'),
              [Input('datatable-upload-container', 'data')])
def update_dropdown(rows):
    print('updating menus')
    numerical_col = [i for i in df.columns if df[i].dtypes != "object"]
    col_labels=[{'label' :k, 'value' :k} for k in numerical_col]
    return col_labels

@app.callback(Output('numerical-slider','children'),
              [Input('data_selector1', 'value'),
              Input('datatable-upload-container', 'data')])
def explanatory_cat_slider(value, rows):
    if value:
        categories, intervals = pd.cut(df[value], 3, retbins=True)
        return html.Div(html.Label([value,
                            dcc.RangeSlider(id='numerical-slider',
                               min=min(intervals),
                               max=max(intervals),
                               step=None,
                               marks={str(val): str(round(val,2)) for val in intervals},
                               value = [intervals[0],intervals[-1]]
                               )
                            ],style={'width': '50%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'textAlign': 'left'})
                        )
    else:
        return []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

updated code...
I am getting an issue with **explanatory_cat_slider**, it's not getting updated with new selected values.

[In the first image I can select one value of dropdown which automatically shows slider of that value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JubAy.png)

[In the second image sliders getting accumulated on upon other. How do I rectify this issue?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kronq.png)

[In the last image, how it becomes slider overlapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDhyu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is incomplete, because you have the Input ID `data_selector` and the ID `datatable-upload-container` in your callback, but they do not exist in your `layout`. I can see that the callback will have a problem with its Output as well, because it's trying to update the `children` of `categorical-checklist` with an element that contains an ID of the same. This would result in non-unique IDs in your layout, which will break.

I may be able to help more with the complete code but, essentially, you have the right idea to check `if value:` and run your code inside that block. Make sure you do not let the callback silently end, because that will return `None` and cause trouble for you. You should include a `return []` or `return ''` at the end, or inside an `else:` block to protect against that, and keep the `children` component valid, even if only with an empty value.

You should also include the `dcc.Checklist` in your initial layout. Give it `options=[]` to start with and have your callback update its `options` prop. That should work but, if there are still problems, update your posted code and I'll take another look.

Comment: Update your callback like I mentioned in the last part of my answer so that the `Output` is the `options` prop of a dropdown and not the `children` prop of a div. As I also mentioned, you're including multiple components with the same ID, which is not valid for Dash. Every ID must be unique.

Comment: Thank you. The issue is with ID. Now I made all unique IDs.

Comment: Please look into this question once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60604550/how-to-get-all-selected-values-of-dynamically-selected-dropdown-in-a-single-list