# How to get all selected values of dynamically selected dropdown in a single list?

Tags: python, dynamic, callback, output, plotly-dash

How do I get all values of dynamically selected dropdown in a single list?
I tried doing callback inside callback with for loop iteration, but unable to get the desired list.

The issue with **def a_function** where callback inside a callback is present.

How to get in a single list of multiple dropdowns which is dynamically updated?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

step = html.Div(
        children=[
            "Menu:",
            dcc.Dropdown(options=[{'label': v, 'value': v} for v in ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']])
        ])

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions']=True

div_list = [step]

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),
        html.Div(id='step_list', children=div_list),
        html.Div(id='local'),
        html.Button('Add Step', id='add_step_button', n_clicks_timestamp='0'),
        html.Button('Remove Step', id='remove_step_button', n_clicks_timestamp='0'),
        html.Div(id='tester_div'),
        html.Div(id='tester_div_2')])

@app.callback(
    [dash.dependencies.Output('step_list', 'children'),
    dash.dependencies.Output('local','value')],
    [dash.dependencies.Input('add_step_button', 'n_clicks_timestamp'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('add_step_button', 'n_clicks'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('remove_step_button', 'n_clicks_timestamp')],
    [dash.dependencies.State('step_list', 'children')])
def add_step(add_ts, clicks, remove_ts, div_list):
    add_ts = int(add_ts)
    remove_ts = int(remove_ts)
    if add_ts > 0 and add_ts > remove_ts and len(div_list) < 4:
        div_list += [html.Div(children=[
            "Menu:",
            dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown_id_{}'.format(clicks), options=[{'label': v, 'value': v} for v in ['select1', 'select2', 'select3']])
        ])]
    if len(div_list) > 1 and remove_ts > add_ts:
        div_list = div_list[:-1]
    return div_list,len(div_list)


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('tester_div', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('local', 'value')])
def a_function(value):
    all_output = []
    if value:
        for i in range(1,value+1):
            @app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('tester_div_2','children'),
                          [dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown_id_{}'.format(i), 'value')])
            def drop_output(valued):
                all_output.append(valued)
    return all_output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

In this image, the output should be in a list like this: [option2, select1]

[image]

In this image, the output should be in a list like this: [option3, select3, select1, select2]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Dash does not work with components whose IDs are not present at the initial build of the layout. Dynamically adding components like this can only work if those components are already present on the page when it first loads, probably as hidden components which you later reveal. Callbacks within callbacks, as far as I know, won't work for similar reasons, but you can create callbacks in a loop.

You'll need to rework the setup of your layout a bit, and maybe edit your post if you need more help.

Edit:
I think this would be possible with [pattern matching callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks). I hadn't worked with them (they may not even have been released yet) at the time I originally answered, but now I think they're just what this question was calling for. On that page, there's an example that does something very similar to what you want, adding any number of components, and getting a dynamically updated list of the values from each of them in the callback.

Comment: But I don't know how many hidden components I need because my dataset changes everytime.

Comment: Let's think about this from another way. What does each dropdown component need to do? Perhaps there's a way to solve the problem with a fixed number of dropdowns, or a maybe a multidropdown.

Comment: @chinni I updated my answer. If this is still something you're dealing with, I think there's a better way to do it now.

Answer (score 0):

if you have dropdowns in the control id say 'container', then you can easily know the selected values by using below few lines of code:

```
container_ext = [f for f in [container['props']['children'][i]['props'] for i in range(len(container['props']['children']))] if
                   'children' not in list(f.keys())]

label = [p['id'] for p in container_ext ]
values = [p['value'] for p in container_ext ]
All_values = {}

for i in range(len(label)):
    All_values[label[i]] = values[i]
```

Hopefully this works to read all the values from dynamic dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

I used following Derived from dash example to use in text box

[Pattern Matching Callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks)

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, MATCH, ALL

app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button("Add Filter", id="add-filter", n_clicks=0),#button
    html.Div(id='filter-container', children=[]),#filters
    html.Div(id='filter-container-output')#output of filters
])

@app.callback(#add textboxes , index is taken as n_clicks 
    Output('filter-container', 'children'),
    Input('add-filter', 'n_clicks'),
    State('filter-container', 'children'))
def display_textboxes(n_clicks, children):
    new_inbox = html.Div([
        html.Label('Text Input'), 
        dcc.Input(
             id={
            'type': 'dhiraj',
            'index': n_clicks
                },
            value='MTL', 
            type='text'
            )
    ])

    children.append(new_inbox)
    return children

@app.callback(#set outputs dynamic one is this 
    Output('filter-container-output', 'children'),
    Input({'type': 'dhiraj', 'index': ALL}, 'value')
)
def display_output(values):
    return html.Div([
        html.Div('Filter {} = {}'.format(i + 1, value))
        for (i, value) in enumerate(values)
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```